# don't show ToC, LoT, and LoF in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, packages, tocbibind

Is there a way for me not to show these following three in the Table of Contents?

[image]

I used this package `\usepackage{tocbibind}` in order to include Bibliography in Contents, but for some reason these three appeared that I do not want to see in my Contents. Using this package I could add to the Contents with page number, but those three that appeared in the Contents is not OK. Are there any packages that I could use or any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the `tocbibind` package with the options `nottoc`, `notlot`, and `notlof`:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
```

Comment: Thank you for everybody! I used this package and worked out: \usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

Comment: The last option must be `notlof` I think. I cant change it (less than 6 characters.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz - Good catch!! I've fixed the typo per your suggestion. :-)

Comment: Typo check: the curly brace before ``nottoc`` should be a bracket.

Comment: @WesH - Thanks. Fixed.